# Intersection of 2 dataframe with count in PySpark DataBricks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, data-science, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I want the intersection value of 2 dataframe(columns) on unique_ID match ,  and store intersection value in new_column-1 also get count of intersection data in new_column_3. Dataframe I have given below. This code I am executing in PySpark(DataBricks). I dont know how to write code for intersection on pyspark. Your prompt response/support will be highly appreciated.

```
         Pos_id  Emp_id skill_list_p skill_list_e
0 0       1     100          [a]    [a, f, d]
  3       1     101          [a]    [a, b, e]
  6       1     102          [a]    [b, d, c]
1 0       2     100       [d, b]    [a, f, d]
  3       2     101       [d, b]    [a, b, e]
  6       2     102       [d, b]    [b, d, c]
3 0       3     100    [c, d, a]    [a, f, d]
  3       3     101    [c, d, a]    [a, b, e]
  6       3     102    [c, d, a]    [b, d, c]
6 0       4     100       [a, b]    [a, f, d]
  3       4     101       [a, b]    [a, b, e]
  6       4     102       [a, b]    [b, d, c]
```

Expected output is attached:

```
    Pos_id  Emp_id  skill_list_p    skill_list_e    Matched Matched_skills_list Matched_Skills
0   0   1   100 ['a']   ['a' 'f' 'd']   1   {'a'}   a
0   3   1   101 ['a']   ['a' 'b' 'e']   1   {'a'}   a
0   6   1   102 ['a']   ['b' 'd' 'c']   0   set()   
1   0   2   100 ['d' 'b']   ['a' 'f' 'd']   1   {'d'}   d
1   3   2   101 ['d' 'b']   ['a' 'b' 'e']   1   {'b'}   b
1   6   2   102 ['d' 'b']   ['b' 'd' 'c']   2   {'d', 'b'}  d,b
3   0   3   100 ['c' 'd' 'a']   ['a' 'f' 'd']   2   {'a', 'd'}  a,d
3   3   3   101 ['c' 'd' 'a']   ['a' 'b' 'e']   1   {'a'}   a
3   6   3   102 ['c' 'd' 'a']   ['b' 'd' 'c']   2   {'c', 'd'}  c,d
6   0   4   100 ['a' 'b']   ['a' 'f' 'd']   1   {'a'}   a
6   3   4   101 ['a' 'b']   ['a' 'b' 'e']   2   {'a', 'b'}  a,b
6   6   4   102 ['a' 'b']   ['b' 'd' 'c']   1   {'b'}   b
```

[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlMup.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

It may help to think of this from the perspective of how one might do this in SQL. Dataframes are designed to be thought of as a table. The goal described is to create a new column that is the result of a transformation applied to two existing columns.

**In SQL**, this would look like

```
select "emp_id", transformation("skill_list_p", "skill_list_e") as "common_skills" from ...
```

Given that approach, I recommend you look at the [User Defined Functions (UDF's)](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.udf) provided in Apache Spark™.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `udf` in `pyspark.sql.functions`
Here is an example.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T

# Declare an udf which uses set.interection() in python to find intersection between arrays.
array_intersect = F.udf(lambda r1, r2: list(set(r1).intersection(set(r2))),
                        T.ArrayType(T.StringType()))

# Use the udf we declared before to generate a new column which is the intersection between 
# skill_list_p and skill_list_e
df = df.withColumn('matched_skill_list',
                   array_intersect(F.col('skill_list_p'), F.col('skill_list_e')))

# Calculate the size of the intersection.
df = df.withColumn('matched', F.size(F.col('matched_skill_list')))

# Show the result
print(df.show())
```